# How do you rebind a key set by CUA mode in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, cua-mode

In my `.emacs` I have:

```
(cua-mode 1)
```

I would like to use Alt-V for `next-buffer`, but CUA mode sets it to `delete-selection-repeat-replace-region`. I've tried this:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-v"))
(global-set-key   (kbd "M-v") 'next-buffer)
```

This doesn't work, I assume because the global key map is shadowed by the cua mode one, so how do I change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are completely correct, `cua-mode` is shadowing the global map. I believe the solution is:

```
(define-key cua--cua-keys-keymap (kbd "M-v") 'next-buffer)
```